# Excel or VBA to convert unstructured text to column

Tags: excel, vba

How can I convert text to column when the text is unstructured with no proper delimiters.

For example, how can i turn the following lines:

[image: Excel View]

Into something like:

[image]

In Excel the Text to columns don't seem to find the right separator (space, tab,...). I tried in VBA with the following:

```
I1 = Mid(Cells(i, 1), 1, 16)
I2 = Mid(Cells(i, 1), 17, 33)
I3 = Mid(Cells(i, 1), 34, 49)
I4 = Mid(Cells(i, 1), 50, 53)
I5 = Mid(Cells(i, 1), 54, 66)
I6 = Mid(Cells(i, 1), 67, 82)
I7 = Mid(Cells(i, 1), 83, 99)
I8 = Mid(Cells(i, 1), 100, 116)
I9 = Mid(Cells(i, 1), 117, 133)
```

But I get it doesn't work for all columns. For example, for I3 I get many more values that expected like:

[image]

I tried also replacing the tab (in case it existed) like:

```
MyString = Replace(MyString, vbTab, "")
```

But didn't work either.

Is there another way to approach it?

Comment: You may need to use a text editor and a regex to insert a `Text qualifier` (`"` or `'`) around words that go together. Another option, if there are no commas in your data, is to convert the text into a csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an attempt using a custom `ReplaceWhitespace` function, which replaces sections of whitespace in turn depending on their length. As an intermediate step whitespace is replaced with semicolons; unnecessary semicolons are removed as a last step. `Split` [is used to read](https://trumpexcel.com/vba-split-function/) the parsed string to an array, and the [array is used](https://trumpexcel.com/vba-split-function/) to read the result to the worksheet. It should be straightforward to tweak `ReplaceWhitespace` for your specific needs.

Note that this algorithm does not evaluate whether instances of a single whitespace character should be treated as noise (as in "TUBELINES UNASSIGNED") or ar as valid word delimter (as in "Unit Cost"). Therefore, single whitespace as noise is treated as special cases in `ReplaceWhitespace`: `"- -" ~~> "-;-"` and `" UNASSIGNED " ~~> ";UNASSIGNED;"`

Assuming your data from the screenshot is located in range `A1:A4`, this code produces more or less the desired output, as shown in the screenshot below.

**EDIT:** The initial design of `ReplaceWhitespace` was based on trial and error. With a little afterthought I realized that patterns where the number of whitespace characters or semicolons is a [composite number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_number) will be taken care of by those lines in the algorithm that looks for patterns where the number of characters is a prime number. I have updated the code accordingly.

```
Sub ParseUnstructured()
    Dim i As Long
    For Each cell In Range("A1:A4")
        i = i + 1
        ' Clean whitespace:
        sRow = ReplaceWhitespace(cell.Value)
        ' Read to array
        Dim sArray() As String
        sArray() = Split(sRow, ";")
        ' Read to worksheet:
        Range("A1").Offset(5 + i).Resize(1, UBound(sArray)+1).Value = sArray
    Next cell
End Sub

Function ReplaceWhitespace(sInput As String) As String
    Dim sOutput As String
    ' Look for special cases with single-whitespace noise:
    sOutput = Replace(sInput, "- -", "-;-") ' Take care of "----- ----"
    sOutput = Replace(sOutput, "UNASSIGNED", ";UNASSIGNED;")
    ' Look for patterns where the number of "noise" characters is a prime number:
    sOutput = Replace(sOutput, "       ", ";") ' 7 whitespaces
    sOutput = Replace(sOutput, "     ", ";") ' 5
    sOutput = Replace(sOutput, "   ", ";") ' 3
    sOutput = Replace(sOutput, "  ", ";") ' 2
    ' sOutput = Replace(sOutput, " ", "_") ' 1 Optional
    sOutput = Replace(sOutput, ";;;;;", ";") ' 5 semicolons
    sOutput = Replace(sOutput, ";;;", ";") ' 3
    sOutput = Replace(sOutput, ";;", ";") ' 2
    sOutput = Replace(sOutput, "; ", ";") ' Takes care of some leftovers.
    ReplaceWhitespace = sOutput
End Function
```

Result from running `ParseUnstructured()`:

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. I thought I cracked it in only a few minutes until I realized the extra complexity arising from the problem of not knowing whether one single whitespace is or isn't noise. Treating single-character whitespace noise as special cases seems to be a productive solution, but I would be curious to see other solutions as well. (As for the Regex approach I've noted that it can get really slow for large datasets.)

Comment: @Selrac, note my update on how you can streamline the code further by removing redundant statemens.

Comment: I'm missing the last column (Freight Cost)

Comment: I've corrected the missing column with: Range("A1").Offset(LastRowR).Resize(1, UBound(sArray) + 1).Value = sArray

Comment: Thanks, sorry I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

The data you present does have a regular pattern, assuming that the Category can only be one of a few defined words.

One could also assume that UOM has only a few defined words, if Category will only ever be a single word.  For example

- Item: First substring followed by a space
- Description: Variable number of words followed by Category
- Category: From list of defined words
- UOM: From list of defined words
- And then the remainder are all space separated.

From that pattern, we can construct a Regular Expression, and use that in a VBA macro to split the line.
Of course, if the pattern varies from that, the method won't work.  But you'll have to provide examples which encompass all of the variability.

The macro below assumes that Category will be either `ASSIGNED` or `UNASSIGNED`, but you can add more words to the pipe-separated list in the code.

Other assumptions are in the code.

```
Option Explicit
Sub parseLine()
    Dim WS As Worksheet, R As Range, C As Range
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
    Dim vRes As Variant, I As Long

'Set original worksheet/range
'change to suit
'Below uses column A
Set WS = Worksheets("sheet1")
With WS
    Set R = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

'Initialize regex engine
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = "^(\S+)\s+(.*)\s*\b(UNASSIGNED|ASSIGNED)\b\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)"
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .MultiLine = True
    .Global = True
End With

'Iterate through; create the Parse line and parse
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each C In R
    If RE.Test(C.Text) = True Then
        Set MC = RE.Execute(C.Text)
        ReDim vRes(1 To MC(0).SubMatches.Count)
        For I = 1 To UBound(vRes)
            vRes(I) = MC(0).SubMatches(I - 1)
        Next I

        'write the results next to the column)
        With C.Offset(0, 1).Resize(columnsize:=UBound(vRes))
            .Clear
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = vRes
            .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With
    End If
Next C
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Ron Rosenfeld, that seems to work. I find the Regex a bit confusing and it seems like I need to update the Category field every time a new word appears. Would it be possible to change the Regex code to work on fixed spaces like in what is defined in the 2nd line with the '-'?

Comment: @Selrac Probably could.  Or maybe it would be simpler to use `UOM` as a marker, if `Category` was only one word. But since @egalth's approach is working for you, I would just stick with that.